# Visual bug on question with pages of answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82/os-x-applications-you-cant-live-without) there seems to be a bug in the layout of the words 'Your Answer' at the top of the answers section where it drops out of alignment with the pagination control.  See attached image:

[image]

Comment: I'm looking into this now. thanks.

Comment: @Jin It also seems like the whole answer box is running behind the answers. See the gap: http://i.imgur.com/L1ofB.png (I'm on Chrome & OS X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.